# Angular performance : Is ngFor trackby needed when elements are added or removed from array

Tags: angular, performance, ngfor

In ngFor, when an element is added/removed from the array, only the new element is rendered. I dont see any difference by addition of trackby

So, from performance point of view, Is trackby not required when adding/removing elements from list?

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let user of users;">
     {{user.name}}
    </li>
 </ul>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users; trackby: trackByFn">
    {{user.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

update(): void {
    this.users.push(
      { id: 4, name: "Four" },
    )
  }
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-meav7m?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

[image]

Comment: Well it will be required in v17+ if you use the new control flow syntax. Its purpose is to prevent re-rendering the full array anytime the array changes. You'll mostly not notice it until it becomes a problem. Just add it every time